# java PreparedStatement syntax issue

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have the following code

```
public void savePosition(String positionName) {
    String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO positions (name) VALUES (?)";
    try (
            Connection connection = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, positionName);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            ){
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And have a syntax error near , ; . in setString and executeUpdate rows.

For this row

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, positionName);
```

I have

> Syntax error on token ".", @ expected
>
> Syntax error on token ",", . expected
>
> Syntax error on token ";", delete this token

I can't see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've put the entire body of your try statement into the part that's meant to only be for initializing closeable resources. You want:

```
// This part is initializing resources
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    // This part is just statements
    preparedStatement.setString(1, positionName);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```